# junit stream map Java 8

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have the below service, i want to test it, but i couldn't do the test of the mapper using the service

```
@Override
public Optional<List<ProviderDTO>> getAllProvider() {
    return Optional.of(providerRepository.findAll().stream().map(providerMapper::toDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
}

@Test
public void whenFindAll_thenReturnCustomerList() {
    Provider provider = providerInit.buildProvider();
    ProviderDTO providerDTO = providerInit.buildProviderDTO();
    List<Provider> providerList = Arrays.asList(provider, provider, provider);
    List<ProviderDTO> providerDTOList = Arrays.asList(providerDTO, providerDTO, providerDTO);
    when(providerRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(providerList);
    when(providerMapper.toDto(providerList)).thenReturn(providerDTOList); //error
    Optional<List<ProviderDTO>> result = providerService.getAllProvider();
    assertEquals(providerDTOList.size(), result.get().size());
}
```

Comment: Please include the error message. From the looks of it, I would assume that `providerMapper` is not a mock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapper accepts single Provider instance and returns an DTO representation. You are trying to pass a whole list.

In order to simplify your test, use a single object, instead of a whole collection.

```
@Test
public void whenFindAll_thenReturnCustomerList() {
    Provider provider = providerInit.buildProvider();
    ProviderDTO dto = providerInit.buildProviderDTO();
    List<Provider> providerList = Collections.singletonList(provider);

    when(providerRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(providerList);
    when(providerMapper.toDto(any(Provider.class))).thenReturn(dto);

    Optional<List<ProviderDTO>> result = providerService.getAllProvider();

    assertEquals(1, result.get().size()); // check size
    assertEquals(dto, result.get().get(0)); // check dto result
    Mockito.verify(providerMapper).toDto(provider); //verify the mapper
}
```

**Suggestion**:

As for the method `getAllProvider()` it would be cleaner to return an list instead of an Optional. If you are not expecting findAll() to return a null value, there is no point in wrapping results in an Optional. Eventually empty list will be returned.

```
@Override
public List<ProviderDTO> getAllProvider() {
    return providerRepository.findAll().stream().map(providerMapper::toDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```